# Marshaling an array inside a Struct with methods using C# P/Invoke

Tags: c#, c++, c, pinvoke, marshalling

I wrote in C a struct like that

```
struct IMAGE {
    unsigned int    x, y;
    unsigned char   **data;
};
```

Could anybody please tell me how to marshall this struct to use in C#?

my solution does not work.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class IMAGE
{
            public UInt32 x;
            public UInt32 y;

            public byte[][] data;
};
```

Comment: why not simply create struct in c#?

Comment: bacause my work is to wrap a C library for calling by C#.

Comment: [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/8c1f2e87-9d6b-46e7-9402-7de88f3b65de) is one good post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed arrays are different than pointers. A managed array requires the size of the array, and if you're trying to marshal a struct, it requires a fixed size to marshal directly.

You can use the `SizeConst` parameter of the [`MarshalAs` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx) to set the size of data when it gets marshaled.

But I'm guessing that `x` and `y` are the dimensions of the image and that the size of `data` depends on those variables. The best solution here is to marshal it over as an `IntPtr` and access the data when you need it:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class IMAGE
{
    public UInt32 x;
    public UInt32 y;

    private IntPtr data;

    public byte[][] Data
    {
        get
        {
            byte[][] newData = new byte[y][];

            for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
            {
                newData[i] = new byte[x];
                Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(data.ToInt64() + (i * x)), newData[i], 0, x);
            }

            return newData;
        }

        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
            {
                Marshal.Copy(value[i], 0, new IntPtr(data.ToInt64() + (i * x)), value[i].Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you are allowed to use unsafe code, you can change the `IntPtr` to a `byte**` and work with it directly.

With the setter, you'll probably want to verify the dimensions of the value before you blindly write to unmanaged memory.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that it is:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class IMAGE
{
            public UInt32 x;
            public UInt32 y;

            public ref IntPtr data;
};
```

A very handy reference is the p/invoke [cheatsheet](http://khason.net/blog/pinvoke-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: `ref` is used for method parameters, not class members. Your answer generates a compiler error: `Invalid token 'ref' in class, struct, or interface member defintion.`